# Spring Security WebFlux and LDAP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap, reactive

What customization's are required in order to secure a Reactive Spring Boot application with LDAP?  The examples I've seen so far are based on Spring MVC and the example for securing a WebFlux only shows a simple Reactive example with an in-memory Map.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one solution for this that I have come up with and tested.

Deserving special attention is this information in this class: [ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter.html). There, it states:

> Adapts an AuthenticationManager to the reactive APIs. This is somewhat
>   necessary because many of the ways that credentials are stored (i.e.
>   JDBC, LDAP, etc) do not have reactive implementations. What's more is
>   it is generally considered best practice to store passwords in a hash
>   that is intentionally slow which would block ever request from coming
>   in unless it was put on another thread.

First, create a configuration class. This will handle the connectivity to LDAP.

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveLdapAuthenticationConfig {

    // Set this in your application.properties, or hardcode if you want.
    @Value("${spring.ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Bean
    ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {

        BindAuthenticator ba = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        ba.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] { "cn={0},ou=people" } );

        LdapAuthenticationProvider lap = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ba);

        AuthenticationManager am = new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(lap));

        return new ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter(am);

    }

    @Bean
    BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource ctx = new LdapContextSource();
        ctx.setUrl(ldapUrl);
        ctx.afterPropertiesSet();
        return ctx;
    }

}
```

After that, you'll want to configure your security following the patterns [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#explicit-webflux-security-configuration). The most basic chain configuration is about this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

For completeness, you'll want to make sure you have these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Other References**

- [EnableReactiveMethodSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#explicit-webflux-security-configuration)
- [BindAuthenticator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator.html)
- [LdapAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/LdapAuthenticationProvider.html)
- [ProviderManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html)

Answer (score 4):

The above example didn't work for me using Windows Active Directory. I could get LDAP Authentication to work in stand-alone (non-Spring) Java, but the above solution always gave me error 52e (user known, but invalid password).

Following on from the example above, I used the same `pom.xml` and `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` ... `SecurityWebFilterChain(...)`, but with the following;

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveLdapAuthenticatoinConfig {

@Bean
ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {

   ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adlap = 
      new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
         "{my.domain}",
         "ldap://{my.ldap.server}.{my.domain}"
      );

   AuthenticationManager am = new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(adlap));
   return new ReactiveAuthenticationManagerAdapter(am);
}
}
```

In order to return the signed-in user, one would use something like;

```
@GetMapping(value = '/user')
public Mono<String> getUser(Mono<Principal> principal) {
   return principal.map(Principal::getName);
}
```